# Speed up (not turn off) animations in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, speed, animation

Is there a way to increase the speed of all animations in Windows 10?

I know you can disable it entirely through the `System > Advanced Settings > Performance Settings > Visual Effects` tab. But I like the animations and just want them to happen faster.

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: I googled it and searched this site. Most results turned up how to turn off not change the speed. Granted I could've missed something, but it wasn't immediately visible.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't find anything either. It doesn't appear modifying the speed of animation is adjustable in Windows 10, or with 3rd party software.

Comment: I would assume animations will happen faster on a faster system.

Comment: I agree a slow system would choppily chug through the animations. Which is why the feature to turn off is there. But my computer is well above the hardware spec and the animation is very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Damn this old, but I found an article explaining how to achieve that. Heres the [sauce](https://www.maketecheasier.com/windows-menu-animations/).

### Warning

First of all the standard warning, that this will include changing a registry-entry which, when done wrong, **may be able to brick Windows**. So be careful and pay attention.

### Solution

- First open the registry editor: Press "Windows + R" and type in `regedit`, then hit ok. You should be prompted for admnistrative rights from the UAC, hit yes on that and continue
- In the new window find your way to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` (you can copy & paste this path in the box above, easier then to go through everything yourself)
- Now select the entry called `MenuShowDelay` in the right pane, right-click it and modify the value from (default) `400` to anything you'd like. I would suggest changing it to `250`

Congratulations, you have successfully changed the animation speed in Windows!

> Please note, that the changes won't take effect until you have rebooted your machine

Comment: This does not affect the animation speed, it only affect the delay before menu opens.